# Detect when android phone is standing still

Tags: android

I want to know the moment when my android phone has stopped moving, and the moment it has started moving.
For example, im in a car, I stop in a line, I want to know the moment I stopped. When I start driving again, get that moment.
Is there any possible way I can do this, maybe using accelerometer?

Comment: Not easy with the specific scenario, as the momentum applied to the phone is very little. But yes, it is indeed possible. Though if the above scenario is what you are looking for, then I would suggest GPS, looking at the speed value returned as part of the information.

Answer (score 1):

There is `Activity Detection` in Android. You simply register a `PendingIntent` with the OS and  you get a callback with information about the users current activity. They can determine whether the user is in a vehicle, on a bike, walking, running, on foot, still, and tilting (in other words 'changing'). The best part is it is efficient and only uses phone sensors and no GPS data.

You can use this to determine when the user changes from still to on foot or vice versa. Not sure how accurate you need but this may get you started. If you need more accurate you will probably have to use your own logic with the accelerometer.

[Android Activity Detection](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html)